# Cannot create new Simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to test out my app on a old version of iOS (11.0).

1. Press "Add additional simulators" in Xcode's "set active scheme"-selector

[image: Select simulator in Xcode]

2. Click "Download more simulator runtimes..." in the OS version drop down.

[image: Add a simulator in xcode]

3. Download the iOS 11.0 runtime. (also visible by navigating to Xcode Settings -> Components -> Simulators)

[image: Download iOS 11 runtime from Xcode]

After having done this, I expect iOS 11.0 to be visible on the "OS version" drop down from image 2, but it's not.. It looks exactly like image 2.. When closing Xcode and rebooting my Mac and going back in the runtimes list, it still looks exactly like it does on image 3. Runtime is downloaded, but I cannot create it as an simulator.

**How can I create a new simulator after downloading the runtime, when the runtime doesn't appear in the "Create Simulator"-dialog?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `xcrun simctl list runtimes` in the Console reveals which runtimes are currently installed. Here's how that's looks on my system currently:

```
== Runtimes ==
iOS 11.0 (11.0.1 - 15A8401) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-0 (unavailable, The iOS 11.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.)
iOS 11.1 (11.1 - 15B87) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1 (unavailable, The iOS 11.1 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.)
iOS 11.4 (11.4 - 15F79) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-4
iOS 12.0 (12.0 - 16A366) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-0
iOS 14.4 (14.4 - 18D46) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4
tvOS 14.3 (14.3 - 18K559) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-14-3
watchOS 7.2 (7.2 - 18S561) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-7-2
```

Here's the problem is explained: `(unavailable, The iOS 11.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS)`.. So it turns out, that:

**Not all runtimes available for download are supported by the current version of macOS**

*I was unable to find a official reference to which simulators are supported on which os...*

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have them automatically in the Simulators list after the components were installed?
[image]

I never had to create the simulator like this. Usually it's enough to download the components. Sometimes you might need to check the 'Show as run destination' checkmark in order to have it in the run list.

Comment: Nope, I don't :(
Also, I can't check the 'Show as run destination' checkmark, because the newly added simulator doesn't appear in the list of simulators at all.

Comment: Can you see iOS 11 in the list of `xcrun simctl list runtimes` in the console? It also might be useful to check all simulators with `xcrun simctl list`.

Comment: Thanks @ScorpiCon, that provided useful insight.. I've add a answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped rebooting the mac.

This problem occured because of migration to another mac with mac migration helper.